# Ordering: Identity

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Given a unital C*-algebra $1\in\mathcal{A}$.

Denote selfadjoints:
$$\mathcal{S}(\mathcal{H}):=\{A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):A=A^*\}$$

Introduce an order:
$$A\leq A':\iff\sigma(A'-A)\geq0$$

Consider projections:
$$P\in\mathcal{A}:\quad P^2=P=P^*$$

Then one has:
$$P\leq A\leq 1\implies P=PA=AP$$

And equivalently:
$$0\leq A\leq P\implies A=PA=AP$$

How can I check this?

Comment: $Q$ adds confusion. Just assume $P \le A \le I$ and conclude $P=PA=AP$. That's much more intuitive.

Comment: Oh right, thanks!! *(I changed it.)*

Comment: I've noticed this one come up in this same vein: If $P_j$ are orthogonal projections and $I = P_1+P_2+\cdots+P_n$, then show $P_nP_k=0$ for $n \ne k$. I saw that problem on this forum one time. Obviously related to spectral measure, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the square, which gives you the additional step of justifying that $(1-A)^2\leq 1-A$. You can simply do, since $0\leq A\leq 1$ (because $P\leq A\leq Q$),
$$
0\leq P(1-A)P=P-PAP=0,
$$
so
$$
0=P(1-A)P=[(1-A)^{1/2}P](1-A)^{1/2}P,
$$
from where $(1-A)^{1/2}P=0$, and then $(1-A)P=0$.